# new custom filed not showing in taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a new ACF filed to my taxonomy page, but the text isnt appearing.
I have tried

```
<?php the_field('extra_text');?>
<?php the_sub_field( 'extra_text' ); ?>
```

but neither one work.

[Here is the page](https://www.mgmclaren.com/markets/utility-transmission-infrastructure/)

Here is the code:

`?php
get_header();
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$termval='mgm_projects_markets_'.$term_id;
$postcount = $queried_object->count;
$projectcnt = 0;
$parentid = $queried_object->term_id;
$priorities=get_field('featured_projects',$termval,false);
if ($queried_object->parent != 0){
?>

```
                <div class="row textrow">   
                <div id="markets" class='row col-3 post nogutter'>
                <div class="gi span2 description">
                <div class="intro"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
                </div>
```

$term_id,'hide_empty' => false ) );
if ($market_children) {
    echo '

### Submarkets

  ';
       foreach ($market_children as $term) {
          if($term->count==0) echo '
- ' . $term->name . '
  ';
          else echo '
- slug.'">' . $term->name . '
  ';
      }
      echo '

';
}

$services = get_field('market_services',$termval);
if( $services ){
    echo '

### Specialty Services

';
    the_field('',$termval);
    echo '';
    foreach( $services as $service ){
        if($service->count==0) echo "".$service->name."";
        else echo "slug."'>".$service->name."
";
    }
    echo '';
}
the_field('extra_text',$termval);
?>

```
                    </div>
                    <div class="row textrow">
                    <?php $term = get_queried_object();
```

$test = get_field('services_intro',$term);
?>

```
                    <h1 class="pgtitle"><?php single_cat_title('Featured Projects: '); ?></h1></div>
```

```
            </div>
            <div id="projects-index" class="projects-more">`
```

Comment: What have you tried @Robin and where did you get your information - did you check the ACF documentation on the get_field() function and understand how to pass the taxonomy term object to this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on using the_field? It is an ACF function, not part of WordPress: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: <?php $services = get_field('market_services',$termval);
if( $services ){ echo '<div id="services"><h2>Specialty Services</h2>';
 the_field('',$termval); echo '<div id="service-list">';
 foreach( $services as $service ){if($service->count==0) echo "<span class='nolink'>".$service->name."</span>";
  else echo "<a href='../../services/".$service->slug."'>".$service->name."</a><br>";
 }
 echo '</div></div>';
}
the_field('extra_text',$termval);
?>
      </div>
      <div class="row textrow">
      <?php $term = get_queried_object();
$test = get_field('services_intro',$term);
      ?>

Comment: This is what i tried but the text on the front end under get_field('services_intro isnt appearing on the webpage

Comment: Please update your original question so that the code is readable.

Comment: I tried updating it, some came out readable some didnt :(

Comment: Perhaps you can try again ;) This way there is a better chance people can help you out.